Exact solution to integral (Keplerian free fall time)
It is a mathematical problem applied to orbital mechanics for which I cannot calculate an exact mathematical solution.
I have two astronomical objects in space having mass m1 and m2 whose sum is M. The relative radial velocity is v. My target is to determine the free fall time based on Keplerian/Newtonian approach. The radial coordinate is r and the distance between them is a. Starting from the acceleration
$$ acc=-\frac{GM}{r^2} $$
integrating since acc=dr/dt
$$ v^2=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}+2c} $$
where c is the integration constant. I can impose the initial velocity v(t=0)=v and that r=a
$$ 2c=v^2-\frac{2GM}{r} $$
Therefore, substituting in the previous equation
$$ v^2=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}+v^2-\frac{2GM}{a}} $$
Integrating since v=dr/dt
$$ \int_0^T dt = \int_a^0 \frac{dr}{\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}+v^2-\frac{2GM}{a}} }$$
I can identify a constant
$$ k=v^2-\frac{2GM}{a} $$
Therefore, the free fall time T is
$$ \int_0^T dt = T = \int_a^0 \frac{dr}{\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}+k} }$$
I have the Handbook of elliptic integrals of the first kind as suggested to me from some users in other queries. However, I cannot identify this specific mathematical problem in it. Is there an exact analytic solution to this through elliptic integrals or different from elliptic intergals? I prefer not to apply any numerical method. I have been trying with all possible methods incl. part integr. and with WolframAlpha but without success. If the initial velocity is v=0 the problem is easier, but it is not this specific case where the initial velocity is not zero.
Thank you for your support. Mark

@R. J. Mathar   I might have another problem for you. if you have time.

Let $u=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}+k}$ then you obtain a rational function in $u$ which can be integrated using partial fractions or inverse hyperbolic trig identities

if the sum of the masses be $M$, then how can acceleration be $GM/r^2$?

@M.Riyan They're presumably working in the center-of-mass frame. In that case the separation $\mathbb{r}=\mathbb{r}_2-\mathbb{r}_1$ between the two objects does satisfy $\ddot{\mathbb{r}}=-(GM/r^3)\mathbb{r}$. If we take the free-fall case then this simplifies to $\ddot{r}=-GM/r^2$ as stated.

For initial velocity $v(0)=0$ the free fall time $T=\frac{\pi  a^{3/2}}{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{G M}}$

One way to take advantage of @gpmath's result: First, compute the time for the separation to reach the turning point. (Assuming it does: if $v_0$ is sufficiently large then the orbit escapes to infinity.) Then the time remaining is gpmath's result.

@gpmath yes, clear acc. to literature.

@Semiclassical but astronomical objects do have an inital velocity. Therefore, the "approximation" would not give out a reliable result.

There is no approximation involved in what I'm saying. It's the equivalent of tossing a ball up, computing the time it takes to momentarily stop, and then computing the time remaining starting from rest.

Starting with the accelaration
$$r''(t)=-\frac{G M}{r(t)^2}$$
The implicit solution of this ODE is
$$F(r,t,c_1,c_2)=\left(\frac{r \sqrt{c_1+\frac{2 G M}{r}}}{c_1}-\frac{2 G M \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{c_1+\frac{2 G M}{r}}}{\sqrt{c_1}}\right)}{c_1^{3/2}}\right)^2-(c_2+t)^2=0$$
The 2 integration constants $c_1, c_2$ are dependent of the initial conditions $a$ and $v_0$.
$$\underset{r\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}F(r,T,c_1,c_2)=-\frac{\pi ^2 G^2 M^2}{c_1^3}-(c_2+T)^2=0$$
With the solution of the free falling time for $c_1<0$
$$T=\frac{\pi  G M}{\left(c_1^2\right)^{3/4}}-c_2$$
By implicit differentiation we get
$$r'(t)=v(t)=\frac{c_1^{3/2} (c_2+t) \sqrt{\frac{c_1 r+2 G M}{r}}}{\sqrt{c_1} r \sqrt{\frac{c_1 r+2 G M}{r}}-2 G M \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{c_1+\frac{2 G M}{r}}}{\sqrt{c_1}}\right)}$$
With the initial condition $v(0)=v_0$ we can get
$$c_2\to \frac{v_0 \left(a \sqrt{c_1} \sqrt{\frac{a c_1+2 G M}{a}}-2 G M \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2 G M}{a}+c_1}}{\sqrt{c_1}}\right)\right)}{c_1^{3/2} \sqrt{\frac{a c_1+2 G M}{a}}}$$
$$F(a,0,c_1,c_2)=\frac{\left(a \left(c_1-v_0^2\right)+2 G M\right)\cdot \left(a \sqrt{c_1} \sqrt{\frac{2 G M}{a}+c_1}-2 G M \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2 G M}{a}+c_1}}{\sqrt{c_1}}\right)\right)^2}{c_1^3 (a c_1+2 G M)}=0$$
Solution for first factor $a \left(c_1-v_0^2\right)+2 G M=0$
$$c_1\to v_0^2-\frac{2 G M}{a}$$
Finally we get the free falling time to
$$T=\frac{a^2 \left(G M \left(\pi  \sqrt[4]{\frac{\left(a v_0^2-2 G M\right)^2}{a^2}}+2 v_0\right)+2 G M \sqrt{v_0^2-\frac{2 G M}{a}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{v_0}{\sqrt{v_0^2-\frac{2 G M}{a}}}\right)-a v_0^3\right)}{\left(a v_0^2-2 G M\right)^2}$$
With initial velocity $v_0=0$ we obtain
$$T_0=\frac{\pi  a^{3/2}}{2 \sqrt{2G M}}$$
Example
Assuming $G=1, M=1, a=2, v_0=\frac{4}{5}$
Then with $c_1=-\frac{9}{25}, c_2=-\frac{40}{9}-\frac{250}{27} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$
$T=\frac{40}{9}+\frac{125 \pi }{27}+\frac{250}{27} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\approx 27.5749$
Visualization

Addendum
If your programming environment can't handle imaginary arguments, you may use this formula
$$T=\frac{-a\cdot v_{0}^{3}+G\cdot M\cdot \left(2\cdot v_{0}+\pi \cdot \sqrt{{| k|}}+2\cdot \sqrt{-k}\cdot \arctan\! \left(\frac{v_{0}}{\sqrt{-k}}\right)\right)}{k^{2}}$$
with $k=v_{0}^{2}-\frac{2G M}{a} < 0$

astonishing! Well done! However, somehow, something is not working. when I apply real astronomical values into the tanh-1 (ATANH in excel) it does not work. Can you please recheck the argument of the tanh-1 ? Or is it another operator? Might it be?

$\sqrt{k}\cdot \tanh^{-1}(\frac{v_0}{\sqrt{k}})=\sqrt{-k}\cdot \tan^{-1}(\frac{v_0}{\sqrt{-k}})$ if $k<0$
with $k=v_0^2-\frac{2G M}{a}$

$$\tanh ^{-1}(i x)=i \tan ^{-1}(x)$$

One point to highlight here is that, by demanding that the first integration constant be negative, one has restricted attention to $v_0<\sqrt{2GM/a}$. So it seems sensible to organize the solution in a way which emphasizes the assumption $v_0^2<2GM/a$, whereas the present form suggests the opposite assumption.

$v_0=\sqrt{\frac{2G M}{a}}$ is the second cosmic velocity (escape velocity).

@gpmath arctanh and arctan cannot be used interchangeably. Can they? Anyway, I am following with much interest the calculation

Here's a formula which is well-defined for $v_0<\sqrt{2GM/a}$:
$$T=\frac{2GM}{(2 GM/a-v_0^2)^{3/2}}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v_0}{\sqrt{2GM/a-v_0^2}}\right)\right]+\frac{a v_0}{2GM/a-v_0^2}$$
This is based on offline work but should be equivalent to the given expression if the square roots and arctanh are taken appropriately.

@semiclassical  great! Could you derive it? Starting from a soecific point in gomath calculation. The initial velocity is radial and not tangential to irbit right?

With $\frac{\sqrt{-k}}{k^{2}}=\frac{1}{\left(-k\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ Semiclassical's and my formula are equivalent.

@gpmath  could you kindly derive the implicit solution for the ODE in this case? I have the issue that when I manually derive the solution respect to time I do not obtain the "implicit differentation" that you calculated.  There is a deviation despite the derivative is similar. Therefore, I am wondering if the implicit solution you have written might contains errors. Can you pelase check and in case edit the equations? Thank you

As the comment says, consider this:
$$u=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}+k}$$
then, we have:
$$\frac{2GM}{r}=u^2-k$$
$$r=\frac{2GM}{u^2-k}=2GM(u^2-k)^{-1}$$
$$dr=-4GMudu(u^2-k)^{-2}$$
$$dr=-\frac{4GMu}{(u^2-k)^2}du$$
The final limit $r=0$ is not valid here, so we set it as $r=r_0$. The initial limit of $u$ be $u_i$ and final limit be $u_f$. Therefore, the integral becomes:
$$\int _{u_i}^{u_f} \frac{-4GM}{(u^2-k)^2}du$$
To solve the integral
$$\int \frac{du}{(u^2-k)^2}$$
Consider, $u=\sqrt k\cos\theta$, therefore, the fraction becomes:
$$\frac{du}{(u^2-k)^2}=\frac{-\sqrt k\sin\theta}{k^2\sin^4\theta}d\theta$$
$$=-k^{-\frac32}\csc^3\theta d\theta$$
The integration then leads to:
$$-k^{-\frac32}\int \csc^3\theta d\theta=-\frac12k^{-\frac32}[\csc\theta\cot\theta+\ln[\csc\theta+\cot\theta]]$$
The integration is far more tedious than I have expected. Well you can try, using the Kepler's third law, which states $T^2=kr^3$ and find the appropriate $k$ to solve your problem too.

Hi @M.Riyan  Thank you for your quick response. Due to the change of variable, in the main integral u at numerator and denominato should cancel out, shouldn't they? You forgot the "u" at the denominator in your solution. Can you please check it? It leads probably to another result.

Hi @M.Riyan thanks for calculating it again. Apparently, it is very tediuos!

@gpmath could you please kindly show me (quickly) how you pass from the ODE to the implicit solution by involving the inverse hyperb tang ? In this case, I follow exactly  Mryans steps but I cannot identify the tanh-1 funtction in the integral. Thank you

Try this Wolfram Alpha

@gpmath  Thank you. clear. Be patient: how did you obtain the "implicit differentiation" expression. From Wolfram alpha too? Even there or manually I get a complety different result.. please give me an input

@gpmath derivate Divide[r(40)t(41)Sqrt[Divide[2k,r(40)t(41)]+c],c]-Divide[2kArcTanh[Divide[Sqrt[Divide[2*k,r(40)t(41)]+c],Sqrt[c]]],Power[c,Divide[3,2]]]  and see the result

Don't understand what you want to express.
Give you my Mathematica Notebook MSE_Q4957156A

@gpmath go to your previous answer when you state "By implicit differentiation we get".. and you write the r'(t)=v(t).  Where does this expression come from? When I derive it analitically, it is different.

I have integrated the "implicit differentiation" into the notebook.

@gpmath Thank you. I don't want to you to waste your time but something is not correct. If you apply the chain rule to the differentiation respect to time of the "implicit solution".. you do not get the"implicit differentiation" that the program calculates. Just take your "implicit solution" and derive on a paper with your pen. The result is different. For instance, the derivative of the tanh^-1 (x) is 1/(1-x^2) plus the derivative of the arguments. The "implicit differentiation" is much longer than the result in the Notebook. Which I really appreciate though. you are very kind

Maple computes the exact same result, see MSE_Q4957156C.
Do you think you are better than Maple and Mathematica?

@gpmath it is just matter of understannding the derivation. i do not take anything for granted.

Here is a Jupyter notebook Google colab

@gpmath good news. I derived it analitically and it is correct. You are very good with calculation sheets and programming. A good contasct for these kind of queries.

@MarkInt No wonder I'm a SW engineer.

We have the ODE with $k=G M$
$$r''(t)=-\frac{k}{r(t)^2}$$
We multiply the factor $2r'(t)$ on both sides.
$$2r'(t)r''(t)=-\frac{2k}{r(t)^2}r'(t)$$
No we integrate the equation over time
$$r'(t)^2=\int -\frac{2k}{r(t)^2}r'(t)\, dt= \int -\frac{2k}{r(t)^2}\, dr= \frac{2k}{r(t)}+c_1$$
Thus we have
$$r'(t)=\frac{dr(t)}{dt}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{2k}{r(t)}+c_1}$$
With
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2k}{r}+c_1}}\, dr= \frac{r \sqrt{\frac{2 k}{r}+c_1}}{c_1}-\frac{2 k\cdot \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2 k}{r}+c_1}}{\sqrt{c_1}}\right)}{c_1{}^{3/2}}= \int dt + c_2$$
we finally get the implicit solution
$$\left(\frac{r(t)\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2 k}{r(t)}+c_1}}{c_1}-\frac{2 k\cdot \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2 k}{r(t)}+c_1}}{\sqrt{c_1}}\right)}{c_1{}^{3/2}}\right)^2=(t+c_2)^2$$
The integration constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ evaluate to (see my 1st answer)
$$c_1=v_0^2-\frac{2k}{a}$$
$$c_2=-\frac{a v_0}{\frac{2 k}{a}-v_0^2}-\frac{2 k\cdot \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{v_0}{\sqrt{\frac{2 k}{a}-v_0^2}}\right)}{\left(\frac{2 k}{a}-v_0^2\right)^{3/2}}$$
with $a=r(0)$ and $v_0=r'(0)$

thank you, great so far! I am struggling with the expression for the derivation respect to time through wich you calculate the coefficient c1 and c2.  can you explicitly derive it? Even wolfram provides a different result. Thank you
